# In AVAudioEngine The AVAudioPlayerNode output doesn't seem to be the AVAudioUnitNode input

Tags: audiounit, avaudioengine, audiobuffer, avaudioplayernode

I attached an AVAudioPlayerNode to an AVAudioEngine, defined a File linked to the playerNode. I attached an AVAudioUnitNode linked to my own AUAudioUnit.
First time. I connected the playerNode directly to the mainMixerNode and when i start playing the engine i can hear the audio file linked to the player.
Second time. I connected the same playerNode with the audioUnitNode and the audioUnitNode with the mainMixerNode. The audioUnit process method just reads the input buffer's data and write them to the output buffer's data. But i can't hear anything. The input samples of the input buffer of the audio unit are always 0.0.
The debug this i'd like to compare the output AudioBuffer of the playerNode with the one given as parameter of the audioUnit'kernel process method.
But I can't find a way to monitor the output buffer of the playerNode. 
Can someone tell me how to have access to the output data of the playerNode?
Does anyone see what could be wrong in the way I processed or what I have to care about?